# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ms_api_shop

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, lumen

I am using Lumen with Docker to create simple API for authentication. After installing LumenPassport, I cannot migrate the database. I can easily connect to the MySQL db with Dbeaver.
I have already created one Lumen Docker project for the same purpose, it is the second. The first one worked without a problem. Moreover, I have checked the MySQL databases, ms_api_shop was there

Errors: [image]

Here is my docker-compose

```
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Nginx.Dockerfile
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 8092:80
    depends_on:
      - fpm
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/lumen-docker
    links:
      - mysql

  fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/fpm.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/lumen-docker
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql


  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 33006:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=ms_api_shop
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

And env:

```
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=33006
DB_DATABASE=ms_api_shop
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your docker-file, you are binding the `33006` container port to the `3306` of the host port. In case you want to access the MySQL, you should use `3306` not `33006` as you did in your .env

Answer (score 0):

I have a Laravel app running in Docker and a part of my docker config looks like:

But I personally feel that they **should be within a docker network**, look at the last two lines of the code in my `docker-compose.yml` below:

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
```

Comment: I tried but still the same error appeared :(

Comment: turn down containers and build again

Comment: I did it already, I have spent more than 4 hours, even removed the project and created again but no help(

Comment: can you please post your whole `docker-compose.yml` and `.env` file contents? or may be share the link to git repo?

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, docker containers can communicate with each other when they are on the same network. You seem to have not connected these two docker in `docker-compose` yet. To get network information from a container, you can use the below command.

```
$ docker inspect --format='{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks}}'  <docker_container_name>
```

In case you need to connect these two containers, follow these steps:

First, you create a network

```
$ docker network create my-net
```

Second, you connect container to the network.

```
$ docker network connect my-net <docker_container_name>
```

Don't forget to connect these two containers to the network.

Comment: I did exactly you said, created network lumen, connected them with containers and when I inspect I saw it there. But again I got the same error when migrating(